# Google Map infowindow showing last value of loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have used for loop to display the markers and info window. But the infowindow showing only the last value of the loop.

Here is the code im using.

```
  function initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            var geocoder;
            var map;
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.511770, -72.809520);
            var mapOptions = {              
              center: latlng,
               zoom: 9,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
            var markers = JSON.parse('[{"address":"40C Leslie Road,Bridgeport,CT","Description":"Bridgeport - 82 Unit Community"},{"address":"56 Ironwood Road,West Hartford,CT","Description":"West Hartford - 45 Unit Community"}]');
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
           // var address;
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
            {
                var address = markers[i];               
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address.address }, function (results, status)
                {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                    {
                        //map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon:'Images/pin.png',
                            position: results[0].geometry.location
                        });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e)
                        {                       
                            infoWindow.setContent("<div style='border:0px solid red;height:auto;;width:auto;'>" + address.Description + "</div>");
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });

              //  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(41.511770, -72.809520))
            }
        }
       catch (ex)
        {
            alert(ex.message);
        }     
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

Please help me.

Thanks,
Venkat.

Comment: Im curious, does my solution help you or not? If not: provide a comment which is the problem, so maybe I can help you. If yes: considering accepting it as a solution. thnx!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `geocoder.geocode` is an asynchronous function. In other words, your execution moves away from the for loop before your requests has finished retrieving the values. Thus, you will be getting same address values, because it is the last value of the for loop when it had finished and you are placing everything to the same `var address = ...` variable.

To fix this, you need to wrap your `geocoder.geocode` request inside a *self-executing anonymous function*. As a result, your code works properly, because `var address = ...` is defined in it's own scope, together with the requests. See example below:

```
...

// Start of self-executing anonymous function
(function() {

var address = markers[i];  

...
```

and:

```
...

// End of self-executing anonymous function
})();

//  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(41.511770, -72.809520))

...
```

**[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maunovaha/N2g2G/)** (Remember to activate your icon image, I disabled it in that code.)

For further reading, I recommend **[self executing anonymous functions](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/).**

Cheers.